# How can i JSON.stringify some JSON and place into html then parse it in nodejs server by JSON.parse

Tags: json, parsing, cheerio, stringify

I want to stringify some JSON first in html file using javascript then place it in html, after that i'm parsing html using cheeriojs & request in Nodejs and here i want to get that json with JSON.parse() Method, how can i do that.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //stringify json

    var nav = { 
                component : "navbar",
                container_class : "div",
                menu_link_color: "blue",
                hover_color: "white"
            }

    var str = JSON.stringify(nav); 
    document.getElementById('edit').innerHTML=str;      
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wp" id="edit">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Nodejs Code to parse that html with stringified JSON:

```
var url = "http://localhost/test/test.html";
request(url,function(err,res,body){
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('.wp').filter(function(){
        var navbar = $(this);
        var navText = navbar.text();
        var textJson = JSON.parse(navText);
        console.log(textJson);
    });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the job by following these steps:

- Built a JSON object in javascript
- JSON.stringify()  that JSON object
- Place that JSON string into html and hide the display
- Then i have parse that JSON String in nodejs using cheeriojs
- In node server i have JSON.parse() that string and convert it into JSON object which is what i need from html.